# HTTP ERROR 500 when running PHP code on server

Tags: php, variables, http-status-code-500

I've recently created a website front and back end for a client using HTML, CSS, JavaScript/jQuery front end and PHP + MySQL back end. My experience in back end is limited.

I created everything locally and it works great, however now I've uploaded it all to an Apache server - which I have limited access to as it's being hosted by someone else so the client saves a bit of cash - and when loading `index.php` it returns a blank page with an http error 500 on the file request in the network tab on chrome Dev tools, or simply just shows the error on the page.

After some messing around noting out bits of the php to see if I can figure out what's causing it I've noticed the error occurs when defining variables (specifically `$houseGal = [];` but presumably any variable defined). After some extensive googling and logic I figured this had something to do with permissions on the server. Unfortunately the admin of the server hasn't used php in years and has no idea.

Through searching the web I've seen to change the file permission to 755 (originally set at 644), that didn't work. I also tried all permissions (777?) And it still didn't work. I've read a lot about needing to change bits of the `.htaccess` file, however I've looked through everywhere I have access to and it doesn't seem to exist (even after forcing hidden files to show up). I don't seem to have access to any other configuration files except `php.ini` - if that's even one.

As I've said everything worked locally with no issues so I don't think it's my code. I've also tried to turn on error reporting to get more detailed info but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Yup, version 5.3, changed the arrays back to the old style and the same error pops up when using the explode function: "explode(',', string)[1]" guessing this is the same issue, will ask the admin to update the php version and hopefully all should work. Thanks very much. FYI - I did mean cash as in money :P

Comment: Oh, i must have misread that line. Good luck, I've moved my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `[]` in an assignment is known as shorthand array notation. This is only supported in PHP version 5.4 and greater. You will need to use `array()`.

> As of PHP 5.4 you can also use the short array syntax, which replaces array() with [].

-http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0):

check rewrite_mode is enable. if not .htaccess not working.